# Installing TOR on ec2 instance

Tags: software-installation, tor

As part of a research I am doing I am trying to install TOR package on a Amazon ec2 server.

I have added the repo name to my repos configuration (following this tutorial: https://www.torproject.org/docs/rpms.html.en)

When attempting to install the tor package using `sudo yum install tor` I get the following error:

```
> Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package tor.x86_64 0:0.2.7.6-tor.1.rh7_1_1503 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: openssl-libs >= 1.0.1 for package: tor-0.2.7.6-tor.1.rh7_1_1503.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
**Error: Package: tor-0.2.7.6-tor.1.rh7_1_1503.x86_64 (tor)
           Requires: openssl-libs >= 1.0.1**
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

And so I tried to install `openssl` and I found out that it is already installed.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any solutions would be a great help!
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's asking for openssl-libs, not openssl.  You need to install the openssl libraries.

The package may be called openssl-lib / openssl-libs / openssl-devel or something similar.  Try listing all the openssl* packages available to yum, and picking one which indicates it installs the openssl development libraries.

Comment: There is no such package as `openssl-libs` on Amazon Linux (ec2 [Error: `No package openssl-libs available.`])

Comment: How about openssl-devel?  Can you list all the openssl* packages available using `yum`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the folllowing command to see if if openssl-libs is in any of your repos:

```
yum search openssl-libs
```

If you don't see it listed after running a search, you will need to add a repo that provides it.